# remove listener for: firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I listen for token being refresh with:
`firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async function (user) {....})`
However, I just realized I don't delete the listener when required. How can I do this?

Should I use a different method to add listener? I don't understand exactly what is described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `onIdTokenChanged` it returns a method that you can use to unsubscribe the listener.

So capture it with something like:

```
let unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
  }
});
```

And then you can unsubscribe the listener with:

```
unsubscribe();
```

Also see the [reference documentation for `onIdTokenChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#on-idtoken-changed).

Comment: I can't believe it's that simple. Now it works like a charm. 
Is it just me or the documentation can be a bit better?